# I am getting the issue in Form.Item rules message antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, next.js, antd

```
         <Form.Item
      name={[name, 'coin']}
      {...restField}
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: 'Please select coin'
        }
      ]}
    >
      <div className="multi-select-coin">
        <Select
          suffixIcon={
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faCaretDown}
              className="text-light-gray text-14"
            />
          }
          disabled={identifier === 'edit'}
          placeholder="any coin"
          defaultValue={coin}
          value={coin}
          onChange={(value) => {
            if (
              value?.includes('THIS RULE IS IN PROFIT') ||
              value?.includes('THIS RULE IS IN LOSS')
            ) {
              setCoin(value.toLowerCase())
            } else {
              setCoin(value)
            }
          }}
          showSearch={true}
          mode={type === '10' ? 'multiple' : null}
          onSelect={(value) => {
            console.log(value)
            if (value?.includes('THIS RULE IS IN PROFIT')) {
              setType('16')
              setDependOnActionType('')
            }
            if (value?.includes('THIS RULE IS IN LOSS')) {
              setType('17')
              setDependOnActionType('')
            }
            if (value?.includes('COIN FROM ACTION')) {
              setType('14')
              if (options?.[0]?.groupName === 'Actions') {
                options?.[0]?.options?.forEach((ac) => {
                  setDependOnActionType(ac?.isBought)
                })
              }
            }
            if (value?.includes('that coin')) {
              setDependOnActionType('')
              setType('15')
            }
            coinsData?.forEach((c) => {
              if (c.name.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()) {
                if (c.isCoin) {
                  setDependOnActionType('')
                  setType('10')
                } else {
                  setCoin(c?.name)
                  setType(c?.input_type)
                  setDependOnActionType('')
                  if (c?.bundle_id) {
                    setBundleId(c?.bundle_id)
                  }
                }
              }
            })
          }}
        >
          {options?.map((group) => (
            <Select.OptGroup
              key={group?.groupName}
              label={
                group.groupName === 'Create Bundle' ||
                group?.groupName === 'My Bundles'
                  ? (
                  <Space
                    direction="horizontal"
                    className="justify-between"
                    style={{ display: 'flex' }}
                  >
                    <span>{group.groupName}</span>{' '}
                    <a
                      style={{
                        color: '#2EBAC6',
                        textDecoration: 'underline',
                        textAlign: 'right'
                      }}
                      onClick={() => setShow(true)}
                    >
                      View
                    </a>
                  </Space>
                    )
                  : (
                      group?.groupName
                    )
              }
            >
              {group?.options?.map((option) => (
                <Select.Option
                  key={option?.label}
                  value={option?.value.toUpperCase()}
                >
                  {option?.label}
                </Select.Option>
              ))}
            </Select.OptGroup>
          ))}
        </Select>
        {type && type === '10' && (
          <Popover
            className="create-bundle"
            placement="bottom"
            trigger={'click'}
            content={
              <>
                <Row>
                  <Col span={24}>
                    <label className="create-bundle-label">
                      Name the bundle
                    </label>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className="items-center">
                  <Col span={16}>
                    <Input
                      ref={myRef}
                      className="create-bundle-input"
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Enter bundle name"
                    />
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={8} className=" justify-end">
                    <Button
                      className="create-bundle-btn"
                      type="primary"
                      disabled={isCreateBundle}
                      onClick={() => {
                        if (!myRef.current.input.value) {
                          message.error('Please enter bundle name')
                          return
                        }
                        setIsCreateBundle(true)
                        handleCreateBundle()
                      }}
                    >
                      {isCreateBundle ? <Spin /> : 'Create'}
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </>
            }
          >
            Create Bundle
          </Popover>
        )}
      </div>
    </Form.Item>
```

**Antd Form Item issue**
I am getting the warning 'Please select the coin' even I have selected the coin on submit I get this unexpected warning

I am using the antd Form i set the rule in Form.Item if field is empty show the warning message
but the issue is even i select a coin on submit i get warning message

Comment: Components inside Form.Item with name property will turn into controlled mode, which makes defaultValue not work anymore. Please try initialValues of Form to set default value ,https://ant.design/components/form#why-will-resetfields-re-mount-component